# ACCESS_VIOLATION exception (0xC0000005) when using IDirect3DTexture9::LockRect

Tags: c++, directx, textures, directx-9

Using DirectX 9, I am trying to create and then fill in an `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` texture in the following way.

1. First, I create the texture with `IDirect3DTexture9::CreateTexture`:

   ```
   LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 pTexture;

   if ( FAILED( pd3dDevice->CreateTexture( MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH,
                              MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT,
                              1,
                              0,                 // D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC,
                              D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,
                              D3DPOOL_MANAGED,   // D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
                              &pTexture,
                              NULL ) ) )
   {
       // Handle error case
   }
   ```
2. Then, I try and lock a rectangle on the texture as follows:

   ```
   unsigned int uiSize = GetTextureSize();
   D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;
   ARGB BlackColor = { (char)0xFF, (char)0xFF, (char)0xFF, (char)0x00 };
   ::ZeroMemory( &rect, sizeof( D3DLOCKED_RECT ) );

   // Lock outline texture to rect, and then cast rect to bits and use bits as outlineTexture access point

   if ( pTexture == NULL )
   {
       return ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED;
   }

   pTexture->LockRect( 0, &rect, NULL, D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK );          // Consider ?
   ARGB* bits = (ARGB*)rect.pBits;

   for ( unsigned int uiPixel = 0; uiPixel < uiSize; ++uiPixel )
   {
       // Copy all black pixels only
       if ( compositeMask[uiPixel] == BlackColor )
       {
           bits[uiPixel] = compositeMask[uiPixel];
       }
   }

   pTexture->UnlockRect( 0 );

   return ERROR_SUCCESS;
   ```

`ARGB` is just a struct defined as follows:

```
struct ARGB
{
    char b;
    char g;
    char r;
    char a;

    bool operator==( ARGB& comp )
    {
        if ( a == comp.a &&
             r == comp.r &&
             g == comp.g &&
             b == comp.b )
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

    bool operator!=( ARGB& comp )
    {
        return !( this->operator==( comp ) );
    }
};
```

What I want to do is pre-calculate an array of pixel data (a black outline) depending on an in-application algorithm, and then only write the pure black pixels from that set of pixel data onto my `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` to be rendered later.

The application currently throws a ACCESS_VIOLATION exception (0xC0000005) at the LockRect call. Can anyone possibly explain why?

Here's the exact exception detail:

Unhandled exception at 0x0132F261 in TestApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.

The location varied between `0x00000000` and `0x00000001`... Does that hint at anything?

Also, if there's a better way to do what I am trying to do, then I'd be all ears :)

Comment: Did you verify that `pTexture` still points at the same memory address that `CreateTexture()` returns, and hasn't been overwritten with some other value? Are you sure you are calling `LockRect()` only if `CreateTexture()` succeeds? You are not initializing `pTexture` to NULL beforehand, so maybe `CreateTexture()` failed and left `pTexture` pointing at random memory?

Comment: I'm certain it isn't overwriting the same value, and I have a breakpoint set in the failure code for `CreateTexture()` I just set the code to initialize `pTexture` to `NULL` and I get the same error.

I've updated the question with a bit of extra information

Comment: From the code, I can't see anything wrong, please double check your code, and make sure what you post is what you have used.

Comment: Yes, the code is uneditted and is as used. One note is that "part 1" is being done for a lot of different textures and "part 2" is called a fair bit later in the code. I believe the texture pointer is not changing, but rather some extra rouge invalid LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture is making its way in the container somewhere and is the cause of the issue. I'm checking thoroughly now. Thanks for the discussion all; its helpful to know I'm not totally off the rocker on the implementation.

Comment: @Awesomania: an AV accessing an address at/near `0x00000000` typically means a NULL pointer is being accessed.

Comment: Did you tried to lock the texture without the flag `D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK`? I've never used it with my locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other commentators on your question, I can't see anything wrong in principle with the way that you create and lock the texture. I have done the same myself - creating a texture in `D3DPOOL_MANAGED` and using `LockRect` to update the content.

However, there are three areas that concern me. I'm posting as an answer because there's far too much for a comment, so please bear with me...

1. Using the `D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK` flag when locking. I have found that this can cause conflicts when the D3D device has been created for multithreaded operation.
2. The way you access the locked bits takes no account of the stride. I appreciate that the error apparently occurs before this code, but it's worth mentioning anyway.
3. You are casting to your own `struct` for pixel access and it's unclear what the actual size of the `struct` may be because I can't see your packing options for the project.

So, I suggest three things that you can do to identify if any of the above are causing a problem:

First, just use the default zero flag for the locking call

```
pTexture->LockRect( 0, &rect, NULL, 0 );
```

Second, verify that your `ARGB` structure really is 4 bytes

```
ASSERT(sizeof(ARGB) == 4);
```

Finally, do nothing except lock and unlock the texture and see if you still get a runtime error, but also check the return code

```
HRESULT hr = pTexture->LockRect( 0, &rect, NULL, 0 );
ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
hr = pTexture->UnlockRect( 0 );
ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
```

In any case, when updating the texture bits, you *must* do it on a row-by-row basis, taking account of the stride reported back from the `LockRect` call in `D3DLOCKED_RECT.Pitch`.

Perhaps you could update your question with the results of the above and I can amend this answer as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'll definitely take point 2 and 3 into account as I proceed. I've already adjust the code to no longer use D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK without success, but I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was mind-numbingly stupid. Sorry everyone.

I followed the texture pointer all the way through the code; the LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 pointers are actually being stored inside another custom Texture class object type with extra contextual data attached to it; these wrapper objects were members of another class that was being copied and used all over the place, and yet there was no assignment operator or copy constructor written for the class. At some point, out of the huge list of textures being processed, one of the textures sent from the container class was found to be invalid because it actually was; it was supposed to contain a copy of another texture, but contained only an invalid pointer.

Sorry for the unfortunate amateur error everyone, but thank you all for the great pointers and assurance